# Dimmable projector bulb

Tags: dimming

Is it possible to dim a mercury vapor short arc bulb?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it requires a special ballast which you provide a control signal too.

google something like "dimmable hid 1-10v" which will give you some examples.